# Select all text on alert popup selectAll()

Tags: android, keyboard

I use the selectAll() function but it doesnt seem to do anything at all. Is there a way to have the text highlighted so they do not have to backspace and then retype?

```
void GetQuantity()

{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Quantity");
    alert.setMessage("Enter Quantity");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);

    alert.setView(input);
    input.setText("1");

    // android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);


    input.selectAll();

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Quantity =Double.parseDouble( input.getText().toString());
            btnQuan.setText(input.getText().toString());

        }
    });


    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up writing a class for getting numbers and added a spinner too. that way I have 100% control of what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

the actual solution to the problem is this:

for any EditText that you want to use the selectAll() method on, you should declare it's BufferType as TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE.  this allows you to perform selections on a Spannable item.  for more information, look up the Spannable, EditText and Selection classes.  here is a programmatic example:

```
myEditText.setText("mytext", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
myEditText.selectAll();
```

you can also set the bufferType in the xml layout using the 'android:bufferType' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) is standard as of API 11.

To select the text upon focus of your [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), there are ways to do this:

1. In your layout.xml you can specify:

   android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
2. In code you can add an [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html):

   myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
         if ( hasFocus ) {
           ((EditText)v).selectAll();
         }
       }});

Answer (score 0):

Though you've already selected your own answer, here's the fix (using C# and Xamarin, but totally portable to Java):

```
private void InitFocus()
{
    Java.Lang.Runnable rable = new Java.Lang.Runnable(()=> 
    {
        EditText maleCount = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtMaleCount);
        maleCount.RequestFocus();
        maleCount.SelectAll();
    });
    new Handler().Post(rable);
}
```

I post this for people coming across the question in the future, since I had so much trouble finding a solution.